# Error: "self signed certificate in certificate chain" using AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

I have a Azure DevOps pipeline that uses a task AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 to deploy an ARM template and am getting a certificate error

This is my task:

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: PersonalAzureSubs
    subscriptionId: 'my-subscription'
    resourceGroupName: 'my-resource-group-name'
    location: 'North Europe'
    templateLocation: 'URL of the file'
    csmFileLink: '$(StorageContainerUri)qa/my.template.json$(StorageContainerSasToken)'
    csmParametersFileLink: '$(StorageContainerUri)qa/my-parameters.json$(StorageContainerSasToken)'
    overrideParameters: '-ApimServiceName my-apim-service -LinkedTemplatesBaseUrl $(Env:StorageContainerUri)qa -LinkedTemplatesUrlQueryString $(StorageContainerSasToken) -PolicyXMLBaseUrl $(StorageContainerUri)qa/policies -PolicyXMLSasToken $(StorageContainerSasToken)'
```

and this is the error:
[image]

The agent is running on my machine and I've configured it with a ca cert.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused because we used self-hosted Agents behind a corporate proxy and the Azure URL of deployment was inside our network through an ExpressRoute. I needed to update the file ".proxybypass" with a regex representing all urls inside the VNET linked to our corporate network through the Express Route:
[image]

This way the Agent is instructed to not go to the internet asking for a subdomain of appserviceenvironment that is not exposed.